# Cannot invoke with an argument list of type Swift 3

Tags: arguments, swift3

Error happens here

```
    self.iotDataManager.register(withShadow: statusThingName, eventCallback: self.deviceShadowCallback)
```

where

```
    let statusThingName="TemperatureStatus"
```

and

```
    func deviceShadowCallback(_ name:String!, operation:AWSIoTShadowOperationType, operationStatus:AWSIoTShadowOperationStatusType, clientToken:String!, payload:Data!) -> Void {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        //code 

    }
}
```

And signature is

```
 self.iotDataManager.register(withShadow: <String!>, eventCallback: { (<String?>, <AWSIoTShadowOperationType>, <AWSIoTShadowOperationStatusType>, <String?>, <Data?>) in
                <code>
            })
```

I think this could be a  bug in Swift , this is conversion from Swift 2 to 3 that I am trying to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Declaration of the functions:

```
func deviceShadowCallback(
                          _ name: String?,
                          operation: AWSIoTShadowOperationType,
                          operationStatus: AWSIoTShadowOperationStatusType,
                          clientToken: String?,
                          payload: Data? ) {

}

func register(
              withShadow: String,
              eventCallback: (
                              String?,
                              AWSIoTShadowOperationType,
                              AWSIoTShadowOperationStatusType,
                              String?,
                              Data? ) -> Void) {

}
```

## Execution:

```
let statusThingName = "status"
register(withShadow: statusThingName, eventCallback: deviceShadowCallback)
```

I could compile and run it without any problems.

Comment: Probably something wrong with Xcode then in my case. Thank you.

Comment: Any luck with this issue?  Same thing happening here...   My code looks correct as @Wilson